# Ionic - How init mixpanel service?

Tags: ionic-framework, mixpanel

I am developing an ionic 4 app with Capacitor.
I intend to use Mixpanel to tracking info.
But when init the service:

```
this.mixpanel.init(mytoken)
```

I'm catching this error in native device (Android 9):

```
Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.catalogo.myappname. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Why????
What is the relationship between Mixpanel and firebase so that when starting mixpanel it throws me this error?

Btw, only happens in Android. Working fine on iOS platform.